# Please provide a sample query how to order by desc with 2 conditions in a query?

Tags: php, mysql

If there are 3 records with different amounts as 500, 1000 and 1500 respectively, so for default query will be like amount order by DESC, 2nd condition is there is a button like "MOVE TO TOP", if 500 amount user click on button then that record move to top and next records should be display amount wise like 1500, 1000.

If click on "move to top" button then current date will stored in click_date column I am using just default amount DESC query,

move_top table

```
id         name       amount      clickdate
----------------------------------------------------   
1          test       500        2017-02-04 07:25:00
2          test2     1000        2017-02-02 11:18:42
3          test3     1500        2017-02-01 03:26:07
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `move_top`  
ORDER BY clickdate DESC, amount DESC
```

but it's not working properly

Comment: I have seen this question already today...

Comment: When you use `ORDER BY x, y`, it means to order by `x`, but if two rows have the same `x` then you order them by `y`.

Comment: Since all your rows have different dates, the second condition in `ORDER BY` has no effect. I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please make a results example

Comment: Hey show us what you what your end goal is meant to be and we can understand what you need to do :)

Comment: actually the default display will be according to amount decreasing order.  when user click on button i.e "move to top" button click date stored in clickdate column then top most  display will be order by click date and 2nd display is as usual amount wise

Answer (score 0):

Unhapply mysql will not "understand" the logic you need. If you put ORDER BY clickdate DESC, amount DESC, it will order first by clickdate, and if the clickdate are the same then it will order by amount.

A workarround to the result you want(When user clicks MOVE TO THE TOP ):

```
 SELECT * FROM `move_top`  WHERE id = {id_that_user_have_clicked}
 UNION 
 SELECT * FROM `move_top`  ORDER BY amount DESC
```